# jQuery .css does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code and it doesn't seem to work at all. No border is drawn. I there anything wrong? (I have jQuery included correctly because other parts, which use it, work)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').css({"border":"3px solid black"});
});
function setBorder() {
    $('#login').css({"border":"1px solid black"});
}
</script>
<div id="#login">
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Log in" onclick="setBorder();"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of changing CSS rules directly, you should add and remove classes from tags. P.S. The "username:" should be in [`<label>`](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/) tag.

Comment: `<div id="#login">` -> `<div id="login">` as suggested by Quentin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your selector matches "An element with the id 'login'" but your element has the id '#login'.

Remove the `#` from the ID. The character isn't allowed in ids in HTML 4 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You must change `id="#login"` to -> `id="login"`

Answer (score 2):

Two things wrong with your code :

1. the ID login doesn't need the # in the html
2. The .css function you call is $elem.css('property','new value')

Correct code would be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').css("border","3px solid black");
});
function setBorder() {
    $('#login').css("border","1px solid black");
}
</script>
<div id="login">
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Log in"     onclick="setBorder();"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set border is never called also you should not have a # in your id

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').css({"border":"3px solid black"});
     setBorder();

});
function setBorder() {
    $('#login').css({"border":"1px solid black"});
}
</script>
<div id="login">
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Log in" onclick="setBorder();"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you need to remove `#` from the ID, since it isn't allowed as a valid HTML ID:

```
<div id="login">
```

Also, your `setBorder()` can be called from jQuery, not directly with obstrusive JavaScript:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(setBorder);
```

Look at the working sample here: http://jsbin.com/ihixub/edit#javascript,html